# Converting Django QuerySet to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am going to convert a Django QuerySet to a pandas `DataFrame` as follows:

```
qs = SomeModel.objects.select_related().filter(date__year=2012)
q = qs.values('date', 'OtherField')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(q)
```

It works, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Hi @FrancoMariluis, sorry about this out of topic: are you using pandas into django projects. You show graphics using "Plotting with matplotlib" via django web applications. Is a valid solution for you? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, for showing graphics in Django I'm using django-chartit, which works fine, but I'm thinking about using matplotlib, which would give me more flexibility

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward, and it works. Any particular concerns?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you've got it now? Do you have a particular concern?

Comment: This was my first (and only!) approach, but since I am fairly new to pandas, I wanted to see if there was another way, but this seems to be a good one.

Answer (score 153):

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from myapp.models import BlogPost

df = pd.DataFrame(list(BlogPost.objects.all().values()))
df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(
        BlogPost.objects.filter(
            date__gte=datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1)
        ).values()
    )
)

# limit which fields
df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(
        BlogPost.objects.all().values(
            "author", "date", "slug"
        )
    )
)
```

The above is how I do the same thing. The most useful addition is specifying which fields you are interested in. If it's only a subset of the available fields you are interested in, then this would give a performance boost I imagine.

Comment: Using 'list()' seems to have been deprecated (I'm on pandas 0.12). Using `DataFrame.from_records()` works better, i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(BlogPost.objects.all().values())`.

Comment: It would be more clear if this used the names from OP question. For instance, is `BlogPost` supposed to be the same as his `SomeModel`?

Comment: Hi, is there a way to exclude a column you don't need in the dataframe?

Comment: Will this work on "fields" that are a `@cached_property`?

Comment: Thank you, by the way it works without converting to list: `pd.DataFrame(<QuerySet>)` as of now

Answer (score 42):

Convert the queryset on `values_list()` will be more memory efficient than on `values()` directly. Since the method `values()` returns a queryset of list of dict (key:value pairs), `values_list()` only returns list of tuple (pure data). It will save about 50% memory, just need to set the column information when you call `pd.DataFrame()`.

Method 1:

```py
queryset = models.xxx.objects.values("A", "B", "C", "D")

## consumes much memory
df = pd.DataFrame(list(queryset))

## works, but no much change on memory usage
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(queryset)
```

Method 2:

```py
queryset = models.xxx.objects.values_list(
    "A", "B", "C", "D"
)

## this will save 50% memory
df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(queryset), columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"]
)

## It does not work. Crashed with datatype is queryset not list.
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    queryset, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"]
)
```

I tested this on my project with >1 million rows data, the peak memory is reduced from 2G to 1G.

Comment: I was testing this: if the end result is to dump it in a pandas dataframe, then you lose this efficiency. And in fact, keeping it as ".values_list()" and throwing it into pandas using ".from_records()" is much faster for the same memory

Answer (score 32):

Django Pandas solves this rather neatly: https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/

From the README:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    department = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    wage = models.FloatField()

from django_pandas.io import read_frame
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
df = read_frame(qs)
```

Comment: How does Django Pandas deal with large datasets?  https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/blob/master/django_pandas/io.py#L107  This line scares me, because I think it means the whole dataset will be loaded into memory at once.

Comment: @Ada To create a DataFrame using specified field names:`df = read_frame(qs, fieldnames=['age', 'wage', 'full_name'])`

Comment: For those of you in this wonderous future who are wondering wth I was on about, here's a more permanent link to the source at the time:  https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/blob/bce1d59a552c81c91fb8aea7f522fde4a83d0159/django_pandas/io.py#L107

Comment: django pandas able to handle `many-to-many` fields.

Answer (score 2):

From the Django perspective (I'm not familiar with `pandas`) this is fine. My only concern is that if you have a very large number of records, you may run into memory problems. If this were the case, something along the lines of this [memory efficient queryset iterator](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1949/) would be necessary. (The snippet as written might require some rewriting to allow for your smart use of `.values()`).

Comment: @GregoryGoltsov's idea to use `.from_records()` and not using `list()` will eliminate the memory efficiency concern.

Comment: The memory efficiency concern is on the Django side. [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) returns a `ValuesQuerySet` which caches results, so for a large enough dataset, it's going to be quite memory-intensive.

Comment: Ahh yes. You'd have to index into the queryset *and* use `.from_records` without the list comprehension to eliminate both memory hogs. e.g.  `pd.DataFrame.from_records(qs[i].__dict__ for i in range(qs.count()))`. But you're left with that annoying `"_state"` column when you're done. `qs.values()[i]` is much faster and cleaner, but I think it caches.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe can use model_to_dict

```
import datetime
from django.forms import model_to_dict
pallobjs = [ model_to_dict(pallobj) for pallobj in PalletsManag.objects.filter(estado='APTO_PARA_VENTA')] 
df = pd.DataFrame(pallobjs)
df.head()
```