# Tabulating Django data in Pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas

I'm trying to make a reporting / analysis app.

I want to move data from a simple Django 'polls' application into a DataFrame for analysis (basic stats initially). The expected volume of information is low so I am not optimising for performance.

`frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records([row for row in answer_set.values(col_names)], **kwargs)`

I can then 'join' subsequent `frames`(for different questions) on the 'user_id' column, provided I make it an index of the dataframe.

My problem is that an answer is also indexed (but orthogonally) by 'question' and as a result I have only been able to get to a table like this (this is transposed because it was impractically wide):

`answer_fields      User1     User2

questionpk           1          1
question__text     'How?'      'How?'
answerfield1        'x'        'x'
answerfield2        'y'        'z'
questionpk           2          2
etc...`

I want to get a table more like this:

`table                             User     User
question  question_text             1         2
1           'How?'       field1    'x'       'x'
                         field2    'y'       'z'`

But as far as I can see that requires a MultiIndex on the question dimension, making 'users' the columns, and if I cared about organising Users by demographics, I don't think I can have a multiIndex on that dimension too. I prefer this condensed format because I want to offer the ability to build a DataFrame with columns that an analyst user wants to profile and compare (comparing answers with subsequent answers matched on user, most obviously), and while the question_text is redundant as a variable, it has a useful value for reporting purposes. I'd like to offer some tools from statsmodels and patsy formulae, so easy names for columns and rows will be important.

[I have a sense that some kind of set logic among the foreignKeys would help me generalise this to other apps, but having done so badly on what I took to be a simple problem has left me unsure that I understand what a table even is.]

Comment: my suggestion is to just input the dirty data from your Django app (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697887/converting-django-queryset-to-pandas-dataframe) and then just cleaning it up using pandas

Comment: Thanks, yeah I think that'll be best. I have just learned in the cookbook that you can multi-index both Index and Columns, which is pretty important.  Also found (via that answer) a helpful project - (https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/).