# use multiple keys in a list to iterate over a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I have a `list` of dictionaries. From each of the dictionaries, I want to extract information of some of the keys which I saved in a list beforehand. 
I can do it with a `for`-loop, but my `list` length is 15,504,603. It requires a very long time to process. I am looking for alternative ways of doing it.

My list of dictionaries (in reality this is `query_set.QuerySet`):

```py
data = [
{'name': 'Alex', 'employee_id': 1110, 'age': 38, 'rank': 'CEO', 'salary': 'unknown'},
{'name': 'Monty', 'employee_id': 1111, 'age': 33, 'rank': 'EO', 'salary': 2400},
{'name': 'John', 'employee_id': 1114, 'age': 32, 'rank': 'EO', 'salary': 2200},
{'name': 'Max', 'employee_id': 1120, 'age': 26, 'rank': 'OA', 'salary': 1200},
{'name': 'Ginee', 'employee_id': 1130, 'age': 28, 'rank': 'OA', 'salary': 1200},
{'name': 'Adam', 'employee_id': None, 'age': 18, 'rank': 'summer_intern', 'salary': None}
]
```

The information I want to extract are `'name'`, `'age'` and `'rank'`
So I make a list of keys beforehand:

```py
info = ['name', 'age', 'rank']
```

I could do the task by performing a for loop

```py
result = []
result.append(info)
for i in range(len(data)):
    output = [data[i][x] for x in info]
    result.append(output)
```

and finally

```py
for item in result:
    print("\t".join(map(str,(item))))
```

and the result goes like:

```
name    age rank
Alex    38  CEO
Monty   33  EO
John    32  EO
Max 26  OA
Ginee   28  OA
Adam    18  summer_intern
```

In reality there are 15504603 dictionaries with 43 `key : value` within my list which is taking very long time to process. i.e. 22661/15504603 after ~2 hour of running.

What could be the **ideal** and **time saving** ways of doing this?

Comment: The printing is what's making it slow.

Comment: @BrendanAbel No mate, I am using `tqdm` progress bar in  
`for i in tqdm(range(len(data))):`
from this progress bar I can say that it is delayed in this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's making your code slow is mainly the fact that you're building a huge, memory-hogging list just to be iterated over. You should directly print the output line by line as you iterate over the list of dicts instead:

```
print(*info, sep='\t')
for record in data:
    print(*(record[key] for key in info), sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.loc[:,['name', 'age', 'rank']]
```

Comment: It worked. Additionally, I used ```df = pd.DataFrame(list(queryset))``` 
as my data were `QuerySet`  [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55055351/9960542).
However, do you have any idea how to add a progress bar for this operation i.e. `tqdm`

Comment: I guess this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365537/5684634 might help you. Appreciate if you can upvote my answer too. Two cheers if you can accept my answer.

Comment: I am a new user, I cannot upvote yet. :(
However, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365537/5684634 I myself found this, not helping a newbie like me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try `operator.itemgetter`:

```
list(map(operator.itemgetter(*info), data))
```

Output:

```
[('Alex', 38, 'CEO'),
 ('Monty', 33, 'EO'),
 ('John', 32, 'EO'),
 ('Max', 26, 'OA'),
 ('Ginee', 28, 'OA'),
 ('Adam', 18, 'summer_intern')]
```

This is about 6 times faster than the original loop:

```
test = data * 10000
# Given 60,000 dict

%%timeit

result = []
result.append(info)
for i in range(len(test)):
    output = [test[i][x] for x in info]
    result.append(output)
# 36.6 ms ± 314 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit list(map(operator.itemgetter(*info), test))
# 6.92 ms ± 32.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly along with the [answer from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122863/9960542) @Vasu Devan.
However, in a for loop I can add a progress bar with `tqdm`, in this case how should I add a progress bar to it?